# React Can Not SetState After Fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, setstate

I have a component, where i want to render some data after it is successfully fetched, but the SetState Wont Work even after a successful fetch. Even a 'console.log(response.data)' is showing the right object, but Why the 'setGroupData(response.data)' line below it wont change the state?, but returning an empty object instead.

here is the code :

```
const GroupContent = ({ groupContent, changeGroupTitle }) => {
  const groupId = window.location.href.split(
    "http://localhost:3001/groups/"
  )[1];
  const [groupData, setGroupData] = useState({});
  let token = "";

  const getGroupData = async () => {
    token = await localStorage.getItem("token");

    if (token) {
      try {
        const auth = `Bearer ${token}`;
        // console.log(auth);
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/groups/${groupId}`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: auth,
          },
        });
        console.log(response.data);
        setGroupData(response.data);
        console.log(groupData);
        changeGroupTitle(groupData.title);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getGroupData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but please note that `setState` does not update the state immediately, but rather schedules an update to be made.
Therefore I believe that `console.log(groupData)` is still showing the previous state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setState is working fine but the update is asynchronous in nature. You can do couple of things here

1. Convert `setGroupData(response.data)` to `setGroupData(() => ({...response.data}})`
2. Listen to state change using `useEffect` with `groupData` in the depenency array.

Here's some other things which I'd change if I were you:

- Local Storage or session storage operations are not asynchronous. I'd remove the await before the localStorage operation
- I'd rename the function getGroupData to something else that is less confusing, eg. `fetchGroupData`

But these are my personal preferences, the first two pointers will work

Comment: oh my god, why couldn't i think about the useEffect with dependency array earlier, that's just what i needed !, you solved my problem immediately, big thanks !. will remove the await before the local storage, i was wondering if there is something wrong with the token for a while so i tried to put await, which is stupid, and forgot to remove it, removing it now

Comment: You are welcome. Generally speaking, using the local storage to store tokens is a bad idea, however, if you have to use it, at least use the context api to store the token(and the local storage) upon logging in and logging out.

Comment: Yes, i've just learned about the jwt in general and was wondering how to store the token on the client side, Thanks for your suggestion !, again something that i needed :D